# How to make a circle in Keynote using Applescript

Tags: applescript, keynote

How do you make a circle (or eclipse) in Apple Keynote using Applescript?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service! Show us the code that's not working for you. Your question should conform to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help fix your code that's not working for you.

Comment: Sorry!  I can create a rectangle with: `set circle to make new shape with properties {position:{10, 10}, width:30, height:10, opacity:100}` but I cannot figure out which properties to set to make a circle.

Comment: I have to assume you didn't read [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because if you did, you would have edited your question to include the necessary code that we could copy and paste into Script Editor, having only to make minor adjustments, if that. Doing so in order to test your code without having to write all the code around what little piece of code you posted in a comment, to actually have a event take place to analyze. Should we have to fill in all the blanks to help you?